# Google Apps User for Google Form - Automatically checked off "Send me a Copy of my Responses"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

My question pertains to Google Forms.  It is with respect to the  "Send Me a Copy of My response" checkbox.  Is there a way to automatically check this off as the default?  Is there some Google App script that can be written for the live form? Would you be able to provide the script/instructions on how to do this? In addition, would it be possible to gray out that box and ensure that a user cannot deselect the box?

This is critical because I need the person who submitted the form to receive an email from google that contains the EXACT questions and responses that they filled out.

I am familiar with how to compose the script to send the user an email based on 'form responses' for google sheets. However, that solution will not work for this example (for retention & legal purposes).  The user must receive an email from google with the format per the live form.

If anyone can assist in this example, it'd be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

-Stella

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's not possible have that check box set to true by default, via the UI or via Apps Script.